# SVD decomposition with optimization

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting, linear-algebra

Let's suppose there is a matrix A nxn, which will be decomposed into SVD:

[image]

where ui and vi are singular vectors composing matrix U and V. sigma is a vector that contains the eigenvalues. In Mathematica:

[image: ![strong text]

A vector phi might be calculated in terms of a constant lambda:

[image]

What is the easiest way in Mathematica to calculate the vector below?

[image]

Comment: Please include sample code as text, not pictures

Answer (score 7):

The matrix that you are looking for is

```
B = LinearSolve[A\[Transpose].A + \[Lambda]^2 IdentityMatrix[n], A\[Transpose] ]
```

Here a toy example to convince you:

```
n = 6;
\[Lambda] = 1.;
y = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n];
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}];

{U, \[CapitalSigma], V} = SingularValueDecomposition[A];
\[Sigma] = Diagonal[\[CapitalSigma]];

Max[Abs[U.(\[Sigma] V\[Transpose]) - A]]

Btrue = V.(\[Sigma]/(\[Sigma]^2 + \[Lambda]^2) U\[Transpose]);
B = Inverse[A\[Transpose].A + \[Lambda]^2 IdentityMatrix[n]]. 
  A\[Transpose];
Max[Abs[B - Btrue]]/Max[Abs[Btrue]]
```

> 1.44329*10^-15
>
> 9.34098*10^-16

You can compute the action of `B` by Tikhonov regularization by minimizing the function
$$
F_\lambda(x) = ||A \, x - y||^2 + \lambda^2 ||x||^2.
$$

See the section "Relation to singular-value decomposition and Wiener filter"
in this  [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridge_regression#Regularization_in_Hilbert_space).

```
x = Array[\[Xi], n];

{min, sol} = 
  Minimize[Dot[A.x - y, A.x - y] + \[Lambda]^2 x.x, x];

xtrue = Btrue . y;
xTikhonov = x /. sol;

Max[Abs[xTikhonov - xtrue]]
```

> 4.996*10^-16

In general, `Minimize` is by far not the best method because it attempts a global search and because it has quite some symbolic overhead. Better use this if you can afford the matrix factorization of `A\[Transpose].A`:

```
x = LinearSolve[A\[Transpose].A + \[Lambda]^2 IdentityMatrix[n,SparseArray], A\[Transpose].y]
```

If you cannot afford the factorization, then you my try an iterative linear solver. Mathematica as some implementations in the undocumented function `` SparseArray`KrylovLinearSolve ``:

```
f[x_?VectorQ] := A\[Transpose] . (A . x) + \[Lambda]^2 x;

P = SparseArray[
   DiagonalMatrix[1/Map[Dot[#, #] + \[Lambda]^2 &, Transpose[A]]]];
prec[x_?VectorQ] := P . x;

xKrylov = SparseArray`KrylovLinearSolve[f, A\[Transpose] . y,
   "Preconditioner" -> prec,
   Method -> "GMRES",
   MaxIterations -> 1000,
   Tolerance -> 0.00001
   ];
Max[Abs[xKrylov - xtrue]]/Max[Abs[xtrue]]
```

If you have a better preconditioner, then you can overwrite `prec` with it. Here I just use the [Jacobi preconditioner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preconditioner#Jacobi_(or_diagonal)_preconditioner).